# Does ArcGIS API for Python use ArcPy internally?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-python-api

Today I read a GIS SE user opinion in [Using Geometry.distance_to() in ArcGIS API for Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338682/using-geometry-distance-to-in-arcgis-api-for-python) that:

> it appears that ArcGIS API for Python uses ArcPy internally

This surprised me because I do not think that this is the case.

Does the ArcGIS API for Python use ArcPy internally or are they two independent Python libraries that nevertheless may call some common underlying libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the ArcGIS API for Python can use the `arcpy` package if it is available in the current environment.  `arcpy` is not required, but enables some additional functionality if available.

For example:

- the [`arcgis.features.from_featureclass`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html?highlight=arcpy#arcgis.features.GeoAccessor.from_featureclass) function accepts optional parameters if `arcpy` is installed;
- the [`arcgis.features.from_table`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html?highlight=arcpy#arcgis.features.GeoAccessor.from_table) function requires `arcpy`; and
- some [geometry and spatial reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html?highlight=arcpy) object methods require `arcpy`.

The [`distance_to`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html?highlight=arcpy#arcgis.geometry.Geometry.distance_to) method referred to in the [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/338682/2856) you linked to requires either `arcpy` or `shapely`.