# Pycharm settings error "Environment location directory is not empty"

Tags: arcpy, installation, pycharm

I am trying to import arcpy into a script in PyCharm 2021.1. I do not have access to ArcGIS Pro, so I used the advice on [this page](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022005) to clone python 3.7 in Anaconda. I am trying to change the PyCharm python location setting to this clone, but getting this error message in the Virtual Environment setting, ""Environment location directory is not empty."
[image]
I switched to Conda Environment and it allowed the location, and I hit OK to apply it, but then got this error message, "...can't create; no such file or directory."
[image]

How can I get PyCharm to work with ArcPy without ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1):

`arcpy` *requires* ArcGIS Pro and cannot be used without a full ArcGIS Pro install.

However, you can install and use the the [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/) as per the documentation you linked to, but note that this is not `arcpy`. The API will have some [additional functionality](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338712/does-arcgis-api-for-python-use-arcpy-internally) if `arcpy` is installed, but it is not required.

You're trying to create a *virtualenv*, but you have already created (by cloning) a *conda env*. A virtualenv is very different to a conda env. So:

1. select the "Conda Environment", not the "Virtualenv Environment" radio button and
2. Once you've selected "Conda Environment", select "Existing environment" not "New environment" as you've already created the environment outside of PyCharm.
3. Finally, you can install the ArcGIS API for Python.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `venv` folder and try to add the interpreter again. It will solve the error.

[image]